# Error 'This transaction will most likely fail. To save gas costs, avoid executing the transaction.'

Tags: gnosis-safe

I could successfully deployed safe contracts to my side chain, setup the safe-infrastructure, run safe-react app, and can create new Safe. The newly created Safe can receive funds (both native token and ERC-20), the balance is displayed correctly in the UI. The problem is when I try to send the fund out from the safe to another wallet, I've got the error message 'This transaction will most likely fail. To save gas costs, avoid executing the transaction.' in the UI like below.

[image]

I also spot the error below in the web browser console but there's no clue what went wrong. Even though I can forcefully submit the transaction, it failed eventually. Is there a way to figure out what went wrong?

[image]

Comment: This happens if your internal transaction (in your case the Test transfer). There can be many cases for this, depending on the `data` and `to` of the low level transaction. E.g. do you know if the "Tx Sender 1" is a contract? What are the information of the Test coin (how many decimals)?

Comment: Tx Sender 1 is one of my account in Metamask and TEST coin is the native coin of the chain. More information, I read about this safe-infrastructure only support L2 chain, my chain is L1 sidechain so I set all the L2 flags to false (in cfg chain setup and txs proxy contract), not sure if this is not a supported configuration.

Comment: If you are not running a tracing node you will have to use the l2 version. The l2 is maybe not the best name but describes the original purpose of the contracts. It just indicates that the contracts emit more events, therefore can be used without a tracing node.